# InternalViewResolver in spring boot is unable to find the view

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I don't know I have tried multiple times but never really understood how the InternalViewResolver or any view resolver work under the hood. I have configured the view resolution using WebMvcConfigurer. like this one.

```
@Configuration
public class WebViewConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/register").setViewName("registration");
    }
}
```

I have put my html file registration.html in the location: src/main/resources/templates.

Whenever I try to access the page localhost:8080/register I get the whitelabel error page

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

I have configured view like this many times before and I have always faced problem in the beginning but I always get on top of it after some tweak and this time also I know I would get it. So the problem is not just how I solve my current problem but how can I stop this repetitive mistakes. Has any one faced these problems with ViewResolvers in spring or is it just me.

Comment: There should also be a view resolver, right ? Otherwise how does it know how to map to .html extension

Comment: @Mukesh Keshu. I think for jsp and html we don't need to configure it. because in a similar project I had done without configuring a view resolver . Will try to configure once and see.

Comment: I have fixed this issue . I had to provide prefix and suffix to resolve the resource using the InternalResourceViewResolver and the location of resource I had to keep inside the target/classes/resources/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of any one wondering I solved the current problem: I added prefix and suffix in InternalViewResolved and placed the html file in target/class/resources/templates.

My current code after solving:

```
    @Configuration
    public class WebViewConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/register").setViewName("registration");
        }

        @Override
        public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
            registry.viewResolver(new InternalResourceViewResolver(){{setPrefix("templates/");setSuffix(".html");}});
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How logical names are resolved in spring?

Logical names are resolved by DispatcherServelet. And is helped by various view Resolvers . One of which is Internal View Resolver which is a Url based View Resolver.

Follow the stack:

```
getResource:154, PathResourceResolver (org.springframework.web.servlet.resource)
resolveResourceInternal:137, PathResourceResolver (org.springframework.web.servlet.resource)
resolveResource:46, AbstractResourceResolver (org.springframework.web.servlet.resource)
resolveResource:75, DefaultResourceResolverChain (org.springframework.web.servlet.resource)
getResource:560, ResourceHttpRequestHandler (org.springframework.web.servlet.resource)
handleRequest:485, ResourceHttpRequestHandler (org.springframework.web.servlet.resource)
handle:53, HttpRequestHandlerAdapter (org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc)
doDispatch:1040, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doService:943, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
processRequest:1006, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doGet:898, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
service:634, HttpServlet (javax.servlet.http)
service:883, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
service:741, HttpServlet (javax.servlet.http)
internalDoFilter:231, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:53, WsFilter (org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:113, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:113, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:113, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:712, ApplicationDispatcher (org.apache.catalina.core)
processRequest:459, ApplicationDispatcher (org.apache.catalina.core)
doForward:384, ApplicationDispatcher (org.apache.catalina.core)
forward:312, ApplicationDispatcher (org.apache.catalina.core)
renderMergedOutputModel:171, InternalResourceView (org.springframework.web.servlet.view)
render:316, AbstractView (org.springframework.web.servlet.view)
render:1373, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
processDispatchResult:1118, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doDispatch:1057, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doService:943, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
processRequest:1006, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doGet:898, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
service:634, HttpServlet (javax.servlet.http)
service:883, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
service:741, HttpServlet (javax.servlet.http)
internalDoFilter:231, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:53, WsFilter (org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilterInternal:100, RequestContextFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:119, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilterInternal:93, FormContentFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:119, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilterInternal:201, CharacterEncodingFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:119, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:202, StandardWrapperValve (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:96, StandardContextValve (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:541, AuthenticatorBase (org.apache.catalina.authenticator)
invoke:139, StandardHostValve (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:92, ErrorReportValve (org.apache.catalina.valves)
invoke:74, StandardEngineValve (org.apache.catalina.core)
service:343, CoyoteAdapter (org.apache.catalina.connector)
service:373, Http11Processor (org.apache.coyote.http11)
process:65, AbstractProcessorLight (org.apache.coyote)
process:868, AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler (org.apache.coyote)
doRun:1590, NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor (org.apache.tomcat.util.net)
run:49, SocketProcessorBase (org.apache.tomcat.util.net)
runWorker:1149, ThreadPoolExecutor (java.util.concurrent)
run:624, ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker (java.util.concurrent)
run:61, TaskThread$WrappingRunnable (org.apache.tomcat.util.threads)
run:748, Thread (java.lang)
```

PathResourceResolver has a resource variable passed by ResourceHttpRequestHandler which tries to resolve the resource . The resource could be of different types like: ClasspathResource or ServletContextResource.

You can debug the PathResourceResolver.getResource() method to find if in case your resource is not resolved.